# Split path by backslashes and join it with slashes

Tags: powershell

I want to split two paths at the `\` the backslashes and join them with Slashes `/`.

But I get an error that I haven't got the rights for the folder, but I have administrator rights.

```
$PathOne = C:\example\example
$PathTwo = C:\example\example

$PathOne
$PathOne $PathOne("\")
(Get-Content $PathTwo) -Join ("/")
$$PathTwo = $NewPath
$$PathTwo -Split("\")
(Get-Content $PathTwo) -Join ("/")
```

the error is by joining with "/".

> the full error code:
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: Could you edit the question and show what exactly are you trying to achieve? Add any error messages and the actual command(s) that produced the errors.

Comment: What is the aim for, say, `$PathOne $$PathOne("\")` ? The last token `$$` operator is strange a construct here, so is the lack of assignments into the variables and using Get-Content to do, uh, what?

Comment: Are you just trying to turn `C:\example\example` into `C:/example/example`? If so `$NewPathOne = $PathOne.Replace('\','/')`

Comment: Yes James i want to do this and thank you it works

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

To turn `C:\example\example` into `C:/example/example` you can use the Replace Method ([Blog on it](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings/)) like this:

```
$NewPathOne = $PathOne.Replace('\','/')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you have not specified a file that you are trying to considered a get-content command. You must specify the path to the file: get-content c:\patch\textfile.text or: $PathOne = "c:\patch\textfile.text" $PathTwo = "c:\patch2\textfile2.text" (This is an for example - you can choose your path)
If you want to replace separator "\" to "/" try this:

```
    $PathOne = "C:\path1" 
    $PathTwo = "C:\path2"  
    $repl1 = Get-ChildItem $PathOne -Recurse -force   
    $repl2 = Get-ChildItem $PathTwo -Recurse -force   

    $repl1 | % {

    $_.FullName.ToString().Replace("\","/")

    } 

   $repl2| % {

    $_.FullName.ToString().Replace("\","/")

    }
```